# Reference C# Windows Service into an ASP.NET web application, is it possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have developed a C# Windows Service application with certain methods that I would like to call from an ASP.NET web application (it is important that there are these methods returning the result). My initial guess was that I could import the dll of the Windows Service into the web application, but I can find only the executable of the windows service, there's no dll at all.
Is it possible to compile the Windows Service into a dll? And if not, is there some other way I can reference my Web Service into the Web application?

Answer (score 3):

Extract the common functionality into a class library project and reference it from both projects.

Answer (score 0):

Is your windows service hosting a web service or does it just contain code that needs to be accessible in you windows service and web site?

If the former, then you can connect to it via the normal mechanims for connecting to a web service (e.g. adding a service reference in Visual Studio). If the later, then create a class library that both your windows service project and web project can reference (via Add Reference in Visual Studio).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. If you just need the code to be invoked, then you can call the windows service functionality via a custom action on the service, invoked from your code.

However, I gather that what you require is more complex, requiring a response as well. In this case, as per sga101, encapsulate the appropriate functionality into a separate class, and use this in both places. This means that the code projects should both be included in the same solution ( it is not strictly necessary, but it makes it easiest to keep the code matching ).